# Recycler view crashes on scrolling down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash-reports

While I scroll down on my app, the app crashes for no reason and I'm not getting any error reports too.
This is the onbindViewHolder of my adapter class. I think the problem is because I used position variable to fetch values and it get changed fast while scrolling and app is crashing so. Can someone suggest me an alternative for this onBindViewHolder code?

logcat

```
   E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
   E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
   E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
   E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
   E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
   PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
```

onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
    myViewHolder.textView.setText(data.get(position).title);
    myViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(data.get(position).imageId);

}
```

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: post your stacktrace.

Comment: Your title is about crash . So where is the crash report. Add it

Comment: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
 PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
 PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so

Comment: You are probably trying to add null value to the imageView or textview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved when I changed all images with images of low resolution, the image size was the problem. Recyclerview was not able to hold the images with big resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is because I used position variable to fetch values and it get changed fast while scrolling and app is crashing so

This is a wrong assumption. Recycler view won't crash because of the fast scroll.

> Can someone suggest me an alternative to this onBindViewHolder code?

Alternative is not required, there must be some problem in the data

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the debug mode. The crash could occur if the position is superior to number of item in your data list. 
It will show you in any case which line cause you this crash. If you don't have any logs, it could come from somewhere else